# Can I mount an SMB share on a domain inside cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

For whatever reason, my mounted network shares in Windows 7 (e.g, the Z drive) aren’t showing up under Cygwin (connected via ssh).

It may be easier, anyway, to mount them from inside Cygwin. However, it doesn’t like my Cygwin command

```
//data2.einsteinmed.edu/home/mvolaski/cygwin-testing /mnt/data2 cifs credentials=/home/maurice/.dataeinsteincredentials,dom=DM_MONTYNT,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmssp,mfsymlinks,uid=197608,gid=197121 0 0
```

I’m getting the impression from this site, https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table, that the mount command in Cygwin is only partially implemented and there is no way to specify most of these options.

I tried again with the plain command

```
mount "//data.einsteinmed.org/home/mvolaski/cygwin-testing" /mnt/data2
```

and this apparently mounted something. However, I can’t access it because it is giving me permissions denied errors. It would seem without be able to specify what uid, gid to map to, there is no way to access a cifs share via Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT mount external share using Cygwin `mount` as your external share is not yet a `win32path`

```
$ mount --help
Usage: mount [OPTION] [<win32path> <posixpath>]
       mount -a
       mount <posixpath>

Display information about mounted filesystems, or mount a filesystem
...
```

you can however obtain the expected result with a combination of Windows `net use ..`

and Cygwin `mount ..`

Comment: The real problem is that the Z mapped drive shows up in the cygwin terminal but not through an ssh connection.

Comment: what authentification method are you using for ssh ?

Comment: I am using public key.

Comment: https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.shares